# two issues with SSRS report (row number,row size)

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

I have two issues with SSRS matrix report

1- when I auto-generate row number it looks like the pic below

my expression is RowNumber("DataSets") / CountRows()

[row numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pymen.png)

2- the size of the column "saving" is too big. It's not like other columns

[row size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YruW3.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To control the row height, set the `Can Grow` property on the textboxes in the table to `false`. This will prevent the row height from increasing dynamically.

For the column width, this is based on the width you set in the design. Column width doesn't grow or shrink when you run the report. So you will need to set it to the correct size in the design.

Comment: Thanks, sir for your replay
I added fixed size and make CanGrow property to False and I still face the same issue. 
please look to this pic [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1no2qN6npQ_fQvCo5rnZJvOcbs9XCSp7Y/view?usp=sharing)

The description column has many transactions this transactions split into two types "Earning" and "Deduction" this issue happens only with "Deduction transaction"
please look into this pic [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NL3qcO2ga12xltuRKAKqY5kmBFDBUnRy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I solve the first issue by using this expression 
RunningValue(CStr(Fields!Col1.Value)+CStr(Fields!Col2.Value),CountDistinct, "Datasets")